# Angular 2 RC5 add headers to http request is not working

Tags: angular, angular2-http

Simple example, that's not working:

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Authorization', 'Test');
let options = new RequestOptions({
  headers: headers,
  body: {}, //This body empty fix #10668
});
this.http.get('backend url another external domain', options)
  .subscribe((res:Response) => {
  console.log(res);
});
```

Headers are not added to the request.

Noticed that the url I call is external, internal works.

Why headers Map are only sent in local domain with relative paths?

Comment: Not sure but maybe you are dealing with CORS issue?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
let body =    JSON.stringify({ dataToSend });
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

return this.http.post('Url', body, options)
                .map(this.extractData)
                .catch(this.handleError);
```

}

Comment: Sorry, i thought you wanted to send stuff. Mikk is right, most probably your server is not allowing cors

Answer (score 0):

It's a CORS issue. No problem with angular

Answer (score 0):

If using JAX-RS, ensure CorsFilter is updated with headers as below

```
@Provider
public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {
   @Override
   public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext,
                      final ContainerResponseContext cres) throws IOException {
      cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "login, origin, X-Requested-With, content-type, accept, authorization");
      cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
      cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
      cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600");
   }
}
```